# Validating Serial Port input In java

Tags: java, mysql, serial-port

I need to verify the serial port input I am taking and verify it from a database made in mysql.  I already have managed to take serial input but am unable to find anything relevant on the validation part.

Comment: what does validation mean? I suppose you need a connection to your DB using JDBC - tons of examples and the rest of the things is just based on the logic of your application.

Comment: can you suggest a few? I am using java and yes JDBC aswell. My search has been futile.

Comment: so...what are you validating against the DB?

Comment: i have assigned every serial input(rfid card ASCII value) to a user, i need to verify it not validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) a detailed description(maybe to detailed) how you can connect from java using JDBC to a MySQL database. If you already have the serial input just check against the DB what you need.